# Is there a best practice for ensuring the order of Module dependencies in an F# project?

Tags: f#

Example:
I have an F# project with several classes. One of those classes imports (opens) 2 modules as Dependencies.

I note that only 1 of the Dependent modules successfully resolve but there is one that intellisense is throwing an FS0039 error. (The namespace or module [module name] is undefined and as a result I cannot access none of the types or members of the module.

All of the files are in the same directory and the semantics of defining them are for the most part identical.

I spent hours researching trying to determine what was so different for the one module having the issue from the others and finally identified via trial and error that the order in which the Modules were defined in my Project file caused the issue.

So Given

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Module1.fs" />
   <Compile Include="Module3.fs" />
   <Compile Include="Module2.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If Module3 requires Module2, this will cause reference to Module2 to throw FS0039 and the reference won't be resolved. I have to manually re-arrange the order in the Project file in order to resolve the issue.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Module2.fs" />
   <Compile Include="Module1.fs" />
   <Compile Include="Module3.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I note that it doesn't make any difference which module (1 or 2) comes first in the ordering as long as it's listed before Module 3 in this case.

Is there a best practice to alleviate the periodic requirement of manually editing the Project file for F#? Or is this simply par for the course in F#?

I realize this is a procedural based language but I never had to be concerned with manual edits to the Project file in C#.

Comment: File order does matter in F#. If you're using an IDE (ie: something like Visual Studio), you can typically reorder them in the solution explorer directly. There isn't a need to manually edit the fsproj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hurdle that many new F# programmers encounter. The short answer is that part of good design is making sure the dependencies between your compilation units are clean and well-defined, so you naturally learn to keep them in a logical order. As Reed says above, this is usually something you can do in your IDE, rather than mucking with the project file directly.

For a more detailed answer, "F# for Fun and Profit" [covers this topic](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/) well.